# C++ compilation error: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation

Could someone please explain what am I doing wrong here? I am using macOS 
Here are the codes:

//test.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class Test 
{
public:
    Test (std::string, std::string, int);

private:
    std::string par1;
    std::string par2;
    int par3;
};
```

//test.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <string>
#include "test.h"

using namespace std;

Test::Test (string first, string second, int third)
{
    par1 = first;
    par2 = second;
    par3 = third;
}
```

//mainTest.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Test test1 ("A", "B", 2);
}
```

The command I use to compile is :

g++ mainTest.cpp -o mainTest

Here is the error I got:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Test::Test(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int)", referenced from:
      _main in mainTest-056a8f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have searched stackoverflow and google but I still can not figure what I did wrong. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't link with the `test.o`.

```
g++ -c test.cpp -o test.o
g++ mainTest.cpp test.o -o mainTest
```

or you can do them both at once:

```
g++ maintest.cpp test.cpp -o mainTest
```

Comment: oh my god! I feel so dumb, thank you so much, I thought my constructor was wrong.